# How did English gradually change into an analytic language?

Tags: linguistics, language-evolution, germanic-languages

English might be the most analytic language in the IE family, in that it has no case, no gender, and very few personal pronouns. Since PIE and other IE languages are generally synthetic, then what drove English to be so analytic compared to others??

Comment: I edited your question to correct minor grammar mistakes and also to put it in the past tense. English is not changing today. English has been changing for over a thousand years in that direction, and the question is a good one, but it is a historical one. English usage has adapted to the analytic status of English, [by making more syntax as morphology diminished in utility](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/3486/482). But **gradually** is the important word. There is no single force or reason why it went that way.

Comment: Thank you very much John! Yes I understand that this change takes a long time, but my point is that why is it more complete than other nearby languages?

Comment: To be complete, it should also be noted that among the IE languages Bulgarian is also fairly analytic; however, your point stands.

Comment: English currently enjoys being widely used. Before you buy into the idea that it's analytical status is somehow exceptional note that 'Modern Hebrew is much more analytic than Classical Hebrew "both with nouns and with verbs"' [Wikipedia - Analytic_language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_language#Background). So whatever is causing this change doesn't seem to be singling out English.

Comment: Hi @candied_orange.  Chinese has NO inflections whatsoever, but neither Hebrew or Chinese can be considered an Indo-European language which is an essential aspect of the question.

Comment: @Karlomanio well now you're making my point for me. Whatever it is that is driving English to become more analytic doesn't seem to be exclusive English or IE languages. Maybe humans are simply becoming more analytic and our languages are slowly changing to reflect how we think.

Comment: @candied_orange Very true.  Most languages become more analytical over time and less inflectional. Not true with all languages, though, German being a prominent example of this.

Comment: @Karlomanio I suspect that Chinese has strong verbs in various paradigms, like English has in *to be*. Does that count for inflection?

Comment: @vectory I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "strong verbs."  However, there are no inflections in Chinese or Vietnamese indicating past tense or change of person or even inflections to indicate plural of nouns.

Comment: Basically, a lot of "experts" became Pist.

Comment: @vectory Chinese does not have morphology, full stop. A word is a word is a word – it has only one form, regardless of whether it’s a verb, a noun, an adjective, a pronoun, etc. One of the odd things (to a speaker of an IE language) is actually that, while there are generally ways to express the past and future situations, there is no real way to express non-present situations with copulas (those that mean ‘to be’). The particles you use to express the past, for instance, cannot be used with 是 _shì_, the most common copula.

Comment: @Karlomanio German is also becoming less inflectional and more synthetic (it’s currently in the process of losing the genitive case, for instance). It is generally accepted that there is a (very slow) tendency for languages to cycle between morphological typologies; I believe there’s a term for this cycle, but I don’t remember what it is (I keep thinking of Jespersen’s Cycle, but that’s to do with negations). When languages become isolating, they tend to start moving towards agglutination, whence they can then move back to fusional, then analytical, then isolating, etc.

Comment: You have to look at what happened to the morphology. When it stopped being used so often, more use of syntax and analytic status followed. The conventional explanation is the [Grammaticalization Cycle](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Grammaticalization.pdf), which had similar effects on Latin --> Romance.

Comment: @Karlomino, getting off-topic, so expect the comments to be deleted, but Chinese (or was it Japanese only, another analytic language) has a range of words used almost exclusively for or between women.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet arguably German (modern German to say the least) never had a feminine genitive , "der Frau Hund" is simply without morphemes. Whereas *ihr* "her; pl. you" is an honorific, not inflected. Incidentally most women didn't own anything, but were owned. Sociolect plays a huge role, you see.

Comment: @vectory _Der_ is marked as feminine singular genitive. Not unambiguously – no German article is unambiguously marked – but it is morphologically marked. And at any rate _das Haus der jungen Frau_ is certainly morphologically marked. The genitive is as much a category in the feminine as elsewhere. I very much doubt the historical status of female ownership has anything to do with the genitive being currently ousted by the dative in spoken German (_der Dativ ist dem Genitiv sein Tot_).

Comment: @vectory No, sorry, that’s not how German works. You can’t just say _der_ is primarily masculine, because it’s not. It’s just as much genitive feminine. The rest of your comment seems completely irrelevant to the fact that the genitive is slowly on its way out in modern spoken German. It has nothing to do with sociological background or feminines or PIE.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet you might have missed the gist of it. "Der Frau Hund" is practically nonexistent. Since it appears like a purely grammatical backformation to me, I suppose that it was never very current. *der Hund von der Frau* on the other hand is probably not gaining anymore than it always had (comparing the parallel in English, which'd also get's back on-topic). The real problem is *''gen'' des Mann-es* / *von ''dat'' dem Mann*. The real kicker though is that dialectal *von ''nom/akk'' die Frau* seems to parallel English, except that it is never nominative in the masculine, whereas ...

Comment: ... *von ''akk'' den Mann* does exist in my environment and akkusative makes so much more sense. The old *who/whom* debate comes to mind.

Comment: And the only time that I note the difference is in *wegen dem / des Mannes* which actually has akkusative written all over it, but alternation (*in de-m grüne-n Garten*; bad example) seems to be the rule in many cases so *wegen den Mann* is suppressed. We can conclude that the amalgamation of various dialects into a high language is another reason for simplification, if no original system was perfect.

Answer (score 3):

The quoted paper below seems to ascribe this to the time when the Anglo-Saxons were conquered by the French.  Because Anglo-Saxons were the conquered people of the time, they found it necessary to communicate with the French and this profoundly affected English, not only in its vocabulary, but also in its grammar.  The article [summarizes the analytical development of English](https://journals.tdl.org/measure/index.php/measure/article/download/30/26) and its lack of inflectional grammar having resulted from this time period.

> Language changes tend to stem from the want or need to become more regularized or simplified. For example, contact between two distinct yet similar languages produces a basic need to communicate for trading and other common purposes. The inflectional endings, in these particular interactions, become superfluous to the task at hand. Rather than attempt to learn the respective language’s unique
>   inflectional system, two speakers of different languages can instead opt to
>   learn the foreign word absent of its appropriate inflectional morphology.

German in contrast also had a great deal of influence from French as well, but was NOT the result of conquest and didn't have the [profound affect on its grammar](https://journals.tdl.org/measure/index.php/measure/article/download/30/26) as it did in English.

> French influence on the German language and its people, however, occurred not as a result of conquest, but rather admiration. Waterman (1966) notes that even before the Middle High German period, “the prestige of French learning and culture had… been firmly established in Germany” (p. 89). In fact, by the time of the Middle High German period, it was not at all uncommon for the German knights to visit in France, or even to seek service at one of the French courts. Nor was it unusual to find Frenchmen engaged as tutors to the children of German nobles. Thus, in a relatively brief space of time, the German language of the late twelfth and early thirteenth centuries took on many French words, expressions, and turns of speech. (p. 89)

Thus German still kept its largely inflectional language intact.

Comment: Note that many parts of the British Isles were conquered by the Norse at one time or another in the centuries prior to 1066, which would have had a similar effect.

Comment: Compare Afro American English and carribean creole's effect on English; So much for conquest.

Comment: Without using the term, this is the argument that Middle English is a creole. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_English_creole_hypothesis The problem there is that most creoles are based on the dominant language; ME is still a Germanic language with tons of French vocabulary.

Comment: @vectory I'm not sure I completely understand what point you are making, but the circumstances of the Anglo-Saxons' conquest and its effect on English are not necessarily indicative of all conquests, just this one.  Certainly, when a group of people are conquered AND removed from their home country and home language, it only will have more severe effects on their language.

Comment: This is often quoted, but I remain unconvinced that it really played that big a role. Danish was influenced by French (and German) in much the same way that German was, not through conquest or true diglossia – and yet Danish now resembles English more in terms of morphological complexity: no cases, no verbal agreement (even less than English), only two genders left (in some dialects only one). Even Swedish, which was even less influenced by German, is comparable, though they do retain a bit more of their morphology.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet This question is very broad and hard to provide a complete and definitive answer in this type of forum, but nonetheless very interesting and worthy of some discussion. This answer may be just a partial explanation.  I don't have a PhD. in historical linguistics, but I thought that this would be worth providing as an answer and giving some insight as to how English lost its large quantity of inflections vs other languages of similar origin that haven't.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet this just points to a development that started earlier all along the coasts. Normans brought a Germanic language, but Norman French is deemed a Romance language. Creoles start out from a Pigin Language indeed (s. [WT/creole](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/creole); I still confuse *pidging* with *pigeon* for obvious reasons, free like a bird). So, even if armies were recruited from the French backlands, who consequently romaniced Norman (and had influence from Frankish already?), there would be external incentive to learn a trade language. Which had spread I don't know how far

Comment: @vectory The development, as such, started over 100,000 years ago. As far back as we have reasonably solid evidence (that is, back to PIE), this development has been a constant and ever-changing part of language. Within PIE itself, we see new cases and verbal categories added; in PG, cases are lost, the verb loses certain moods and tenses, adjectives develop strong/weak declensions; later on, more cases are lost, more verbal moods and tenses disappear, etc. You can’t pinpoint any moment in time as the ‘starting point’ of all this.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I was rather refering to a pidgin between the Brittish and Continental coast, due to an unbroken continuity of trade with the homeland, which according to Jürgen Udolph includes the area between Rhine and Elbe, as eg. the name *Washington*, if it really relates to *Hessen* ~ *Weser*, would attest to. But the celtic side of things, *do* support for a subjunctive mood instead of a conjunctive as retained in *woulda, coulda, shoulda*, does seem interesting as well.

Answer (score -4):

Innshort: Foreign speakers and rapid growth.

Grossly Simpmifying: The problem is that inheritence in linguistic terms implies an *unbroken descend from parent to child*. To say that the language changed, i.e. changed itself, implies an unnoticable, ever so slight difference from generation to next generation, at least in the usual explanation of sound-shift (I do suppose that hearing impairment due to infection must have been frequent, for one). [Loss](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_change#Loss) of morphemes can stem from sound shift, if sounds in various environments are lost. Reading of course slows the process, but only if a significant number of speakers can read.

Anyhow, there is no unbroken descend when foreign speakers adapt. Rather, they speak broken English to various success. The Norman invasion marks the start of Middle English. The rest is history as they say. In other words, to be honest: I don't know nearly half enough about the history, or the olde Languages; Just living in a city with 10+ % foreign speakers gives a good idea of the effect, though I have no idea under which conditions this could overcome the native speakers. Loss of irregularities is preferable, I suppose (viz. gender that has little to no semantics).

German on the other hand, since a comment mentioned, has a hint of slavic influence, which has even more cases (I'm generelizing from Russian, scold me if that's wrong), and vice versa (e.g.*Grenze, nischtz [nichts]*).